# Node cannot have more than one incoming/outgoing edge

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

I am trying to start using jbpm and I am following this tutorial.
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbpm5/jbpm-5-tutorial-first-example?start=1
On the second page I have to add a diverge gateway, converge gateway, constrains, change the type to XOR, and create a variable "money". When I try running the program I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This type of node cannot have more than one incoming connection!
    at org.jbpm.workflow.core.node.ActionNode.validateAddIncomingConnection(ActionNode.java:50)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.NodeImpl.addIncomingConnection(NodeImpl.java:100)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.ConnectionImpl.connect(ConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.core.impl.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:71)
    at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.ProcessHandler.linkConnections(ProcessHandler.java:293)
    at org.jbpm.bpmn2.xml.ProcessHandler.end(ProcessHandler.java:145)
    at org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.endElement(ExtensibleXmlParser.java:422)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.read(ExtensibleXmlParser.java:301)
    at org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.read(ExtensibleXmlParser.java:180)
    at org.jbpm.compiler.xml.XmlProcessReader.read(XmlProcessReader.java:46)
    at org.jbpm.compiler.ProcessBuilderImpl.addProcessFromXml(ProcessBuilderImpl.java:262)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addProcessFromXml(PackageBuilder.java:673)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:709)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:51)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:40)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.readKnowledgeBase(ProcessMain.java:31)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:79)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.readKnowledgeBase(ProcessMain.java:32)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:20)
0    02/04 10:05:21,243[main] ERROR builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.newKnowledgeBase  - ProcessLoadError: unable to parse xml : Exception class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : This type of node cannot have more than one incoming connection!
```

I tried debugging, by deleting nodes/edges until I got different errors. If I delete a whole branch, the error will be that gateways need 1+ edges. If I delete edges from one of the branches it will say that the script has more than one incoming/outgoing edge. It seems to be that the second script with different id and name, is being confused with the first or there are edges that I cannot see.

Extra Questions:
1. How do i know which node it is referring to? (I am using eclipse, and the links that normally would send you to a code line do not show anything)

Screenshot of the problem:
![[http://imgur.com/0gL5twY][1]](http://imgur.com/0gL5twY%5d%5b1%5d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your process diagram image? 
It is making reference to an ActionNode which is usually a Script Node. 
I will recommend you using the web process designer which is much better in terms of features and validations.

Regards

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was not in town. I uploaded the process diagram image.

Comment: The reason I am not using Web Process Designer is because according to the tutorial is suppose to work without it. This means I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what.

Comment: Trying to use Web Process Designer and getting error saying that server was not up, I decided to look for a reason, and after doing a new complete install..server indeed doesn't go up. This is the log from the server http://pastebin.com/mqjKzaJ6

Comment: This is definitely the issue: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990 you have another instance of the JBoss Application Server running in your machine or something else using the 9990 port, you need to fix that first.

Comment: Seems like Nvidia NetworkServices uses that port too. Thank you.